# Ambassador to bird like race. She communicates via sign language

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I'm looking for a book from the 90s or maybe the 80s. An Alien Academy graduate goes to a planet to be an ambassador to a bird-like race. She lives with them in a nest and learns their dances and communicates via sign language.

Comment: Congratulations on getting your accounts merged. Good luck with the site!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may be A.C. Crispin's *StarBridge* series, specifically the second book, *[Silent Dances](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1560606.Silent_Dances)*, published in 1990.

[image: Front cover of *Silent Dances*]

> Deaf since birth, Tesa is the perfect ambassador to the alien Grus, whose sonic cries can shatter human ears.
>
> But her mission is harder than it looks. The Grus are not alone on their world.
>
> They have deadly enemies, both natural and otherwise. And if Tesa is to save all life on the planet, she will have to make peace with not one alien species... but -two-.

From the TV Tropes entry on [Signed Language](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/UsefulNotes/SignedLanguage):

> The second book in A.C. Crispin's StarBridge series deals with a species of crane-like aliens who communicate primarily in sign; vocalization is used only as emphasis or warning...and their voices are so loud and piercing that they do physical damage to fragile human eardrums. The protagonist is a deaf cultural interpreter who is brought in to live with them, meaning that most of the book's dialogue is in sign.

Comment: THAT'S IT!! Thank you SOOOO much!! Sorry, the system doesn't recognize me to check that was the correct answer. I had to create a new profile.

Comment: As per Skooba's comment on your other post, you can merge your accounts as per https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous